# Помогите пожалуйста как с помощью цикла foreach разобрать данный ответ от вконтакте

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {    
    ["response"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (5) { 
        ["items"]=> array(1) { 
            [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) { 
                ["type"]=> string(10) "wall_photo" 
                ["source_id"]=> int(-55591693) 
                ["date"]=> int(1401529886) 
                ["photos"]=> array(6) { 
                    [0]=> int(360) 
                    [1]=> object(stdClass)#4 (12) { 
                        ["pid"]=> int(330728573) 
                        ["aid"]=> int(-7) 
                        ["owner_id"]=> int(-55591693) 
                        ["user_id"]=> int(100) 
                        ["src"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207c7/t8ZzoT-pWpY.jpg" 
                        ["src_big"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207c8/RF8hkGZ7Ozc.jpg" 
                        ["src_small"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207c6/lTNsYfKtBdk.jpg" 
                        ["width"]=> int(604) 
                        ["height"]=> int(475) 
                        ["text"]=> string(0) "" 
                        ["created"]=> int(1401529885) 
                        ["access_key"]=> string(18) "c6e174c0230d2158ca"
                    } 
                    [2]=> object(stdClass)#5 (12) { 
                        ["pid"]=> int(330728567) 
                        ["aid"]=> int(-7) 
                        ["owner_id"]=> int(-55591693) 
                        ["user_id"]=> int(100) 
                        ["src"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207ab/exs7UXuhcMk.jpg" 
                        ["src_big"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207ac/cVe5b1_u1Nk.jpg" 
                        ["src_small"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207aa/SDO6HZ-Se_0.jpg" 
                        ["width"]=> int(604) 
                        ["height"]=> int(470) 
                        ["text"]=> string(0) "" 
                        ["created"]=> int(1401529885) 
                        ["access_key"]=> string(18) "985736a9362456bffa"
                    } 
                    [3]=> object(stdClass)#6 (12) { 
                        ["pid"]=> int(330728568) 
                        ["aid"]=> int(-7) 
                        ["owner_id"]=> int(-55591693) 
                        ["user_id"]=> int(100) 
                        ["src"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207b2/x9L3D1qgEnc.jpg" 
                        ["src_big"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207b3/M3EYKQ4D3q4.jpg" 
                        ["src_small"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207b1/EBSA6vHlhSQ.jpg" 
                        ["width"]=> int(459) 
                        ["height"]=> int(604) 
                        ["text"]=> string(0) "" 
                        ["created"]=> int(1401529885) 
                        ["access_key"]=> string(18) "2e50a27a6b8941d55a"
                    } 
                    [4]=> object(stdClass)#7 (12) { 
                        ["pid"]=> int(330728569) 
                        ["aid"]=> int(-7) 
                        ["owner_id"]=> int(-55591693) 
                        ["user_id"]=> int(100) 
                        ["src"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207b9/YgcyFUpiHcQ.jpg" 
                        ["src_big"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207ba/3rBvABI0DpQ.jpg" 
                        ["src_small"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207b8/K_eSUFje1vc.jpg" 
                        ["width"]=> int(463) 
                        ["height"]=> int(604) 
                        ["text"]=> string(0) "" 
                        ["created"]=> int(1401529885) 
                        ["access_key"]=> string(18) "ea38f94aea7f992f2d"
                    } 
                    [5]=> object(stdClass)#8 (12) { 
                        ["pid"]=> int(330728572) 
                        ["aid"]=> int(-7) 
                        ["owner_id"]=> int(-55591693) 
                        ["user_id"]=> int(100) 
                        ["src"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207ce/xlwJHIyR_0M.jpg" 
                        ["src_big"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207cf/JaUufudpqDI.jpg" 
                        ["src_small"]=> string(62) "http://cs540109.vk.me/c540102/v540102726/207cd/l86uEpRag6A.jpg" 
                        ["width"]=> int(445) 
                        ["height"]=> int(604) 
                        ["text"]=> string(0) "" 
                        ["created"]=> int(1401529885) 
                        ["access_key"]=> string(18) "f0d6905075293fcc32"
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        ["profiles"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> object(stdClass)#9 (8) { 
                ["uid"]=> int(69567195) 
                ["first_name"]=> string(16) "Р’Р»Р°РґРёРјРёСЂ" 
                ["last_name"]=> string(22) "Р‘РµСЂРµР¶Р°РЅСЃРєРёР№" 
                ["sex"]=> int(2) 
                ["screen_name"]=> string(7) "4ymamba" 
                ["photo"]=> string(53) "http://cs619729.vk.me/v619729195/a9bb/OByjzCeW5ZU.jpg" 
                ["photo_medium_rec"]=> string(53) "http://cs619729.vk.me/v619729195/a9ba/dxLCb3kZm3I.jpg" 
                ["online"]=> int(0) } 
            [1]=> object(stdClass)#10 (8) { 
                ["uid"]=> int(211991675) 
                ["first_name"]=> string(8) "РЎР°С€Р°" 
                ["last_name"]=> string(14) "Р›РёРїРѕРІС‹Р№" 
                ["sex"]=> int(2) 
                ["screen_name"]=> string(7) "par1son" 
                ["photo"]=> string(53) "http://cs322523.vk.me/v322523675/acca/ZUPtO75IjoE.jpg" 
                ["photo_medium_rec"]=> string(53) "http://cs322523.vk.me/v322523675/acc9/JTmwoH9IcSM.jpg" 
                ["online"]=> int(0)
            }
        } 
        ["groups"]=> array(2) { 
            [0]=> object(stdClass)#11 (8) { 
                ["gid"]=> int(55591693) 
                ["name"]=> string(18) "Р’РµСЃРµР»СЊС‡Р°Рє" 
                ["screen_name"]=> string(8) "i_jovial" 
                ["is_closed"]=> int(0) 
                ["type"]=> string(4) "page" 
                ["photo"]=> string(53) "http://cs311825.vk.me/v311825675/6e9b/HMVniZ9T3yE.jpg" 
                ["photo_medium"]=> string(53) "http://cs311825.vk.me/v311825675/6e9a/mkQKkrK7HOc.jpg" 
                ["photo_big"]=> string(53) "http://cs311825.vk.me/v311825675/6e99/xofClo0ASus.jpg" } 
            [1]=> object(stdClass)#12 (8) { 
                ["gid"]=> int(37283109) 
                ["name"]=> string(58) "РћР±СЉСЏРІР»РµРЅРёСЏ Р’РѕСЂРѕРЅРµР¶Р° | Р‘Р°СЂР°С…РѕР»РєР°" 
                ["screen_name"]=> string(5) "vrn_c" 
                ["is_closed"]=> int(0) 
                ["type"]=> string(5) "group" 
                ["photo"]=> string(53) "http://cs619821.vk.me/v619821693/1b2e/_DwfGhFJyi0.jpg" 
                ["photo_medium"]=> string(53) "http://cs619821.vk.me/v619821693/1b2d/d2RtRMYd5W8.jpg" 
                ["photo_big"]=> string(53) "http://cs619821.vk.me/v619821693/1b2c/S895VucD69M.jpg"
            }
        } 
        ["new_offset"]=> int(1) 
        ["new_from"]=> string(23) "-55591693_1401480000_16"
    }
}
```

Comment: Я вам исправил форматирование. Стала понятнее структура ответа ВК?

Comment: @wowa: У вас проблема именно с foreach? Пользуйтесь другим циклом и не морочьте голову.

Comment: Да, стало намного понятнее, но проблему не решает!

Comment: @wowa тут не делают работу за вас, но с удовольствием помогают вам самому с ней справиться. Где конкретно вы застряли сейчас?

Comment: на данный момент есть запрос 
$sRequest = "https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/newsfeed.get?access_token=".$vkontakteAccessToken."&count=1";
$oResponce = connect($sRequest);
$obj = var_dump (json_decode($oResponce));
после которого нужно вывести в цикле например все ["screen_name"], я в php не селен. вот и застрял именно с циклом foreach

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screen_name` встречаются там в двух местах: в `profiles`, и в `groups`. К примеру, группы можно получить так:

```
$vkData = json_decode( $oResponce);
$groups = $vkData->response->groups; // $groups это массив
foreach( $groups AS $G) { // а каждый $G это объект
    echo $G->screen_name;
}
```